# jquery select event handler for combobox

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, combobox, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Daniel Ferell's Combo Box for bootstrap 
https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox

which works great but, it disables the normal select method behavior.  How can I still track the selection after something has been choosen?

Ie normally I'd do:

```
$('#target').select(function() {
  alert('Handler for .select() called.');
});
```

But instead it's been converted into a DIV with the new class combobox-selected once a result is choosen, how can I hook onto that new behavior instead?

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.combobox').combobox();
  });
```

Output

```
<div class="combobox-container combobox-selected"><select name="place[city_id]" id="place_city_id" class="combobox"><option value=""></option>
<option value="4f6e1a8125ae0baf6f000033">Kraków</option></select><input type="text"><a data-dropdown="dropdown" class="add-on btn dropdown-toggle"><span class="caret"></span><span class="combobox-clear"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span></a></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the source of combobox it looks like you should listen for the change event instead.

```
$('#target').change(function() {
    alert('Handler called.');
});
```